# tkinter: How to properly update GUI as a result of separate process in TKinter?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to write a Python programme with TKinter and selenium, that checks internet connection, and if there is no internet connection, it goes to a specific page of my internet provider and enters my login and password (I need this because the internet keeps disconnecting every 30 minutes of inactivity).

So I am trying to do multiple stuff at the same time with tkinter, what I need at the moment, is a function that updates GUI based on whether internet is connected or not every 100 ms. This is basically the visualization of internet connection status.

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/chromedriver.exe'
STATE = False
URL = 'URL ADRESS OF LOGIN PAGE OF MY PROVIDER'

def _selenium_driver():
    #your login and password information
    LOGIN = "login"
    PASSWORD = "password"
    
    #option not to open a chrome window, and run
    #the app in background instead
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")
    
    #start the Chrome Driver, and access URL
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    driver.get(URL)
    
    #find the appropriate fields by name and fill
    #in with data. Names can be found by inspecting
    #elements by right-clicking the element in chrome
    login = driver.find_element_by_name("loginid")
    login.send_keys(LOGIN)

    pswd = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    pswd.send_keys(PASSWORD)

    login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    driver.quit()

def isInternetOn():
    # tries opening google IP address,
    # returns false if unsuccessful
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142', timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib.request.URLError as err: 
        return False
      
def updateConnectionStatus(tk,root,canvas):
    print('is in updateConnectionStatus')
    
    if isInternetOn():
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text= "Connected")
        canvas.create_window(160, 190, window=label1)
    elif not isInternetOn():
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text= "Reconnecting")
        canvas.create_window(160, 190, window=label1)
    root.after(100,updateConnectionStatus(tk,root,canvas))

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 250)
canvas1.pack()

root.mainloop()
root.after(100,updateConnectionStatus(tk,root,canvas1))
```

The problem with this code is that it only enters 'root.after' on the last line, after I close the window, so basically after mainloop finishes. How can I make it, so it will on the background automatically always check connection and update the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `root.mainloop()` line to the bottom of your file.

You also need to use the proper call in the next-to-last line and also in the function, like this:

```
root.after(100,updateConnectionStatus, tk,root,canvas1)
```

You should also update the Label, rather than create a new one every time.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. I tried moving the `root.mainloop()` to the last line, but without reorganizing the arguments I was passing to `root.after()` so it didn't work before. I now assume that root.after is somewhat like a decorated, that's why it expects the function arguments passed after the function and to function itself on recursive call.

Comment: @ArslanGabdulkhakov yeah kinda, but `after` is NOT recursive, it's a normal method that adds something to the event queue, so you can't use your recursive logic here.